# how can I install matplotlib in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have alredy installed matplotlib on my venv in Pycharm. I tried to run it in Jupyter Notebook and them I got noticement `No module named 'matplotlib'`

I also tried to run `!pip install matplotlib` at the first cell in my .ipynb file and then I got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (3.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.45.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.21 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (10.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\user\pycharmprojects\ege\venv\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib) (1.16.0)
```

after that I tried to start code at the second cell: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

and I got this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I also tried: `pip install ipykernel`

what should I try to solve this problem?